# How can I make a Tight VNC server's display mirror its client's display?

Tags: vnc

I have installed the Tight VNC server program on a Linux PC and the client program on a Windows PC. After I launched the server program, I was able to connect to the server with the client by entering the server's IP and password.

How can I set the machines up so that any update or change in the client's window is reflected in the server's window?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to "share" the VNC session. When you start VNC server, set it to use the "shared" option, then connect to it from BOTH the client AND the Linux box, and then you can see what's happening from both systems. How you would do this exactly depends on which VNC you've installed.

Also, if we're just talking about getting a user's session who's logged in at the Linux PC, then, in Ubuntu at least, you can share your desktop with "System", "Preferences", and "Share Desktop".